# How can I use regex to split a string on everything that is not a character

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, character

How could I use vanilla javascript and regex to split on every character that is not a string? Example:

```
var src = "wer%55";
```

and have it return the array as

```
"wer","%","55"
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is a character for you? And what is a non character?

Comment: When I say character I mean all letters of the alphabet and numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/(\W+)/` for splitting and make sure to group `\W+` (1+ non-word characters) to be able to return it in the resulting array:

```js
var src = "wer%55";

console.log(src.split(/(\W+)/));


// add filter(Boolean) to discard empty values from result array

src = "wer%55#";

console.log(src.split(/(\W+)/));
console.log(src.split(/(\W+)/).filter(Boolean));
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by the word boundary `\b`:

```js
var src = "wer%55$$abc33";

console.log(src.split(/\b/));
```

**Or**

Use String#match to get sequences of word / non word characters:

```js
var src = "wer%55$$abc33";

console.log(src.match(/\w+|\W+/g));
```